# Scala group By First Occurrence

Tags: scala, group-by

I have the following data:

```
List(Map("weight"->"1000","type"->"abc","match"->"first"),Ma‌​p("weight"->"1000","‌​type"->"abc","match"‌​->"third"),Map("weig‌​ht"->"182","type"->"‌​bcd","match"->"secon‌​d"),Map("weight"->"1‌​50","type"->"bcd","m‌​atch"->"fourth"),Map‌​("weight"->"40","typ‌​e"->"aaa","match"->"‌​fifth"))
```

After grouping by "type" i would want results of first "abc" then "bcd" then "aaa"

When I apply group by "type" the resulting map gives first key as aaa whereas I want the first key to be "abc" and all corresponding values.

how can I achieve this?

Comment: Please give the code where you apply the groupBy

Comment: a.groupBy { x => x("type") }

Comment: A `Map`'s keys are not ordered. Use a `SortedMap` if you want them to be.

Comment: Okay sorry should have been more clear here. This List is already sorted by values int value. So i thought group by will first see occurance of the first map and group all corresponding types with "abc" and so on.
Basically i wantd that groups should be made on basis on "value" as well. higher value groups first

Comment: Example:
List(Map("weight"->"1000","type"->"abc","match"->"first"),Map("weight"->"1000","type"->"abc","match"->"third"),Map("weight"->"182","type"->"bcd","match"->"second"),Map("weight"->"150","type"->"bcd","match"->"fourth"),Map("weight"->"40","type"->"aaa","match"->"fifth"))
After grouping by "type" i would want results of first "abc" then "bcd" then "aaa"

Comment: It would be better to add the code and data above to the question.

Comment: Are you still  seeking help with this? Otherwise consider accepting an answer.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments you need a sorted map, which is not created by a simple group by. What you could do is:

```
val a = List(Map("weight"->"1000", "type"->"abc","match"->"first"), Map("weight"->"1000","type"->"abc","match"->"third"),Map("weig‌​ht"->"182","type"->"‌​bcd","match"->"secon‌​d"), Map("weight"->"1‌​50","type"->"bcd","m‌​atch"->"fourth"), Map("weight"->"40","type"->"aaa","match"->"‌​fifth"))
val sortedGrouping = SortedMap.empty[String,String] ++ a.groupBy { x => x("type") }
println(sortedGrouping)
```

What you get (printed) is:

```
Map(aaa -> List(Map(weight -> 40, type -> aaa, match -> ‌​fifth)), abc -> List(Map(weight -> 1000, type -> abc, match -> first), Map(weight -> 1000, type -> abc, match -> third)), bcd -> List(Map(weight -> 1‌​50, type -> bcd, m‌​atch -> fourth)), ‌​bcd -> List(Map(weig‌​ht -> 182, type -> ‌​bcd, match -> secon‌​d)))
```

Comment: Im sorry i was not clear with the problem. Can you see the example in the question again

Comment: Oh, now I see. You don't want the results to be sorted, but retain the order in which they were found in your list, right?

Comment: I believe OP wants `Map` sorted by the order of appearance of keys. Ruby `Hash` works this way, only I don't think Scala has something like this out of the box.

Comment: Jeah, I don't know of an out of the box solution too. For sure you cannot use the standard groupBy for this. You might have to do it by hand.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is out of the box solution for what you are trying to achieve. `Map` is used in two ways: get a value by a key, and iterate over it. The first part is unaffected by a sort order, so `groupBy` works perfectly well. The second part can be achieved by creating a list of keys in required order and then using that list to get key-value pairs from `Map` in a specific order. For example:

```
val xs = List(Map("weight"->"1000","type"->"abc","match"->"first"),
              Map("weight"->"1000","type"->"abc","match"->"third"),
              Map("weight"->"182","type"->"bcd","match"->"second"),
              Map("weight"->"150","type"->"bcd","match"->"fourth"),
              Map("weight"->"40","type"->"aaa","match"->"‌fifth"))

import collection.mutable.{ListBuffer, Set}

// List of types in the order of appearance in your list 
val sortedKeys = xs.map(_("type")).distinct

//> sortedKeys: List[String] = List(abc, bcd, aaa)
```

Now when you need to iterate you simply do:

```
val grouped = xs.groupBy(_("type"))

sortedKeys.map(k => (k, grouped(k)))
//  List[(String, List[scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,String]])] =
//  List(
//    (abc,List(Map(weight -> 1000, type -> abc, match -> first),
//              Map(weight -> 1000, type -> abc, match -> third))),
//    (bcd,List(Map(weight -> 182, type -> bcd, match -> second),
//              Map(weight -> 150, type -> bcd, match -> fourth))),
//    (aaa,List(Map(weight -> 40, type -> aaa, match -> ‌fifth)))
//  )
```

Comment: the first part can also be achieved by this:
xs.flatMap{i=>i.get("type")}.distinct

Comment: @Sidhant Agree, somehow I missed it.